# listview doesn't update after retrieving data form database

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, android-listview

I want to make a program that read data from contact list and add them to the database and then update a listview that contain selected data. but every time I click add button and contact list open and i select one item, listview doesn't change. I also don't know where the database is stored.
     main activity:

```
public class BlockActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<String> contactnumber= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> contactname= new ArrayList<String>();
public static SQLiteDatabase database;
SQLiteDatabase myDB= null;
CustomAdapter adapter;



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button pickContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

pickContact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // user BoD suggests using Intent.ACTION_PICK instead of .ACTION_GET_CONTENT to avoid the chooser
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);  

}
});
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {

            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME},
                        null, null, null);


                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    Log.i("error", "salalalalal");

                    String number = c.getString(0);

                    String name = c.getString(1);


                     manageDatabase(name, number);
                                        }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void manageDatabase(String name, String number) {

    String TableName = "contact";


    /* Create a Database. */
    try {
     myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

     /* Create a Table in the Database. */
     myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
       + TableName
       + " (" +
       "name TEXT, " +
       "number TEXT" +
           ");"
       );

     /* Insert data to a Table*/
     myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
       + TableName
       + "(name,number)"
       + " VALUES ('name','number');");

    // retrieve data from database
     Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName , null);


     // Check if our result was valid.
     c.moveToFirst();


     if(c.moveToNext()){
         while(!c.isAfterLast())
            {
             Log.i("error",c.getString(0));
             Log.i("error",c.getString(1) ); 
         contactname.add(c.getString(0));
         contactnumber.add(c.getString(1));

         c.moveToNext();
         }}



      //fill the list view with results from database

      ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

       adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, contactname, contactnumber);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);





    }
    catch(Exception e) {
     Log.e("Error", "Error", e);
    } finally {
     if (myDB != null)
      myDB.close();
    }




}





}
```

here is custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


private final Activity context;
private final ArrayList<String> nameList;
private final ArrayList<String> phoneList;
public CustomAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<String> nameList, ArrayList<String> phoneList) {
        super(context, R.layout.detail, nameList);
        this.context = context;
        this.nameList = nameList;
        this.phoneList =phoneList;


        }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, null, true);
TextView word1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.one);
TextView word2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.two);

 word1.setText(nameList.get(position));
 word2.setText(phoneList.get(position));

return rowView;
  }


}
```

main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="add" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

detail.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="30dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip" android:background="#ff7f7f"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the data in View, you should call his adapter.

```
((ArrayAdapter) mMyListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: where should I use it?

Comment: After data is downloaded. I could not find this point in your code.

Comment: Ii dosent download a database. It only usees query .

Comment: Then I do not understand your problem. When the upgrade is to View?

Comment: List view update wrongly. this line  contactname.add(c.getString(0)); only give the first row. 
         c.moveToNext();
has not any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView if the data is not stable!